# Responsive Images EE4 best solution?

Tags: ee4, responsive-images

I'm looking to do responsive images with EE4, where you serve smaller versions of an image for mobile devices. Can anybody recommend a good method? I've noticed many references to CE Image, but it appears that's only up to EE3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CE Image is an excellent choice. Although Aaron doesn't specifically support EE4 with this add-on, I have had a client directly contact him and be told that the latest EE3 version should work with EE4. And for myself, it does. I currently have two EE4 sites that I did the upgrade work on that use CE Image with EE4 and we haven't noticed any issues or loss of functionality.

The add-on is a plugin, and plugins are the simplest add-on types. They essentially just expose PHP methods to a template, and usually don't interact with EEs internal APIs at all.

Reach out to Causing Effect about it, but it should work for EE4 out of the box.

But buyer beware; and it would be best if you are a developer yourself so you if you do run into minor bugs, you can fix them yourself.

Comment: I'm using CE image withe EE4, for the momemt no problems encountered.

Answer (score 2):

`CE Image` is the all time great solution for Resizing/Responsive images for `EE`. If you've `CE Image` version `3.0.1` then no need to worry about it. It will definitely work for you. There is no special version for `EE4`, version`(3.0.1)` is fully compatible with `EE4`. You can rock with it.

Answer (score 2):

Bought CE Image (for EE3) and it works perfectly with EE4, following the tutorial at https://www.aaron-gustafson.com/notebook/adaptive-images-in-expressionengine-with-ce-image/. To quote the important part of that page, use this code, replacing {embed:image} with your image URL:

```
<img class="page__image-header__photo" alt=""
{exp:ce_img:pair
src="{embed:image}"
filename_suffix="_small"
width="480"
height="320"
crop="yes"
interlace="yes"
cache_dir="/"
}
src="{made}"
srcset="{made} 480w,
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
{exp:ce_img:pair
src="{embed:image}"
filename_suffix="_medium"
width="800"
height="600"
crop="yes"
interlace="yes"
cache_dir="/"
}
{made} 800w,
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
{exp:ce_img:pair
src="{embed:image}"
filename_suffix="_full"
width="940"
allow_scale_larger="yes"
crop="yes"
interlace="yes"
cache_dir="/"
}
{made} 940w"
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
>
```

To produce this output:

```
<img class="page__image-header__photo" alt=""
src="about_480_320_int_c1_small.jpg"
srcset="about_480_320_int_c1_small.jpg 480w,
about_800_350_int_c1_medium.jpg 800w,
about_940_343_int_s_c1_full.jpg 940w">
```

That produces a working demo. Then naturally you'll modify for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Channel Images from Ee harbor I think (before it was Devdemon )

Comment: Yes fully compatible with EE4

Comment: I've been using Channel Images for EE2 for years now. It's always worked great--DevDemon's software's always been great. Since this is still supported I'll look into this, as well.